# trim not working in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a one line function that works great in Chrome, and FF to shorten a string but throws an exception in IE.  Does anyone know of a workaround for IE?

Here is my code:

```
var name = 'This is a really loooooooooooong string';

var shortName = name.trim().substring(0, 10).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "...";

alert(shortName );
```

Thanks,
-Paul

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`trim` was standardized in ECMAScript 262 5th Edition, so it should be available in IE 9.  For IE 8 and older, there are a couple of solutions available to you.

Since you tagged jQuery, you can use `$.trim(str)`:

```
$.trim(name).substring(0, 10).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "...";
```

Alternatively, you can implement `String#trim` using a shim, like this one:

```
if(!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/, '');
  };
}
```

There's also a decent comparison on different `trim` implementations [available at Steven Levithan's blog](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript).

Comment: didn't realize jquery had a trim method...works great! thanks

Comment: You legend! Saved my day. Godforsaken IE8.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

Comment: @vsync See Paul's comment on previous answer.

Comment: sorry my bad. I guess I completely don't get what jquery's trim has to do with what he wants to achieve.

Comment: +1: Valid and simple. *A full example, showing how it solved the question's problem, would have avoided the down-vote*. :)

Answer (score 0):

This one works perfectly in IE, Firefox, Chrome:

```
   String.prototype.trim = function () {
        return this.replace(/^\s+/, "").replace(/\s+$/, "");
    }
```

The advantage over jQuery is that it extends the String prototype and you do not need to adjust any code.

Edit: adjusted according to AndyEs comment

Comment: Yet the advantage of jQuery.trim is that it's readily available if you're already using jQuery.  Which is the case here, since the OP tagged [tag:jquery].

Comment: @Andy thats true. But as you may see in his example he`s using trim() on a String object. If his script is complex it might cost him a lot effort to adjust his scripts and probably introduces regression problems.

Comment: @AndyE No need to stick jQuery where it doesn't belong.

Comment: @VahurRoosimaa: nobody is sticking jQuery anywhere - it's already there. I'm not against implementing the shim, in fact, I included it in my answer, too. However, I don't believe that suggesting the OP may be able to use `jQuery.trim` warrants a down vote.  IMO, if you're introducing regressions by swapping `str.trim` with `$.trim(str)`, it might be time to look for a different profession.

Comment: As for your own shim, I would use `\s+` rather than `\s*`, because the latter will *always* match.